Uniformity in Birkhoff averages under exponential mixing
Let us suppose we have a collection indexed by $\alpha$ of Markov chains $X_n^\alpha$, on a Polish space $X$, with transition kernels $P^\alpha$, and which satisfy the following uniform exponential mixing property: for any $f \in C_b(X)$, there holds
$$
\sup_{x\in X} \left|(P^\alpha)^k f(x)-\int_X f(y) d \pi^\alpha (y)\right| 
\\ \leq Ce^{-\lambda k}\|f\|_{\sup}
$$
where $\pi^\alpha$ is the unique invariant measure for $X^\alpha$, and $C, \lambda$ are independent of $\alpha$.
I was wondering if this uniformity in the speed of convergence can also imply some sort of uniformity in the rate of convergence of the associated Birkhoff averages. More precisely, given an initial value $x$, can we say something along the lines of “There exists an $N(\omega)$ so that for all $n\geq N, \alpha$ there holds”
$$
\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f(X_j^\alpha)-\int f d\pi^{\alpha}\right|<\epsilon
$$
Or some variation on this? Perhaps it might be easier to obtain some uniformity in the rate of convergence in probability to this limit?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
